# tensorboard written in the jupyter notebook doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I run the code

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
m = tf.Variable(0.)
y = m*x
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y - y_, 2))
update = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(loss)

msum = tf.summary.scalar('m', m)
losssum = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

sess = tf.Session()
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
data_dict = {x:[[7.01], [3.02], [4.99], [8.]], y_:[[14.01], [6.01], [10.], [16.04]]}
for i in range(0,1000):
   [_,curr_sammary] = sess.run([update,merged], feed_dict = data_dict)
   file_writer.add_summary(curr_sammary, i)

file_writer.close()
print(sess.run(m))
```

But this code is not running because of the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-c57f3c0f3525> in <module>()
      1 data_dict = {x:[[7.01], [3.02], [4.99], [8.]], y_:[[14.01], [6.01], [10.], [16.04]]}
      2 for i in range(0,1):
----> 3    [_,curr_sammary] = sess.run([update,merged], feed_dict = data_dict)
      4    file_writer.add_summary(curr_sammary, i)
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 345, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1312, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2901, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-8fcfa2faf332>", line 3, in <module>
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1734, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4924, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

After trying to understand the source of the problem I saw that if the line

```
[_,curr_sammary] = sess.run([update,merged], feed_dict = data_dict)
```

in the loop I change the line

```
sess.run(update, feed_dict = data_dict)
```

the problem is solved.

I tried to search for understand what the error was and didn't find anything to solve the problem.

I need the line to work in its original form (without the deletions)

I would be happy if someone can tell me what the problem is and what its solution is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on `tensorflow-gpu (1.7.0)` and the original, unedited version

`[_,curr_sammary] = sess.run([update,merged], feed_dict = data_dict)`

runs successfully runs with no errors on both `Jupyter` and on the terminal.

---

I DID, however, notice that when i ran the script a second time on `Jupyter`, that I got the same error as you. This leads me to believe you're keeping state between runs.

On the terminal (where no state is kept between consecutive runs), it all worked fine